# Python: How can I multithread many queries across many DBs

Tags: python, mysql-python, python-multithreading

I am attempting to drastically reduce my MySQL job time using multi-threading.  I have a few servers with 700 + DBs where I need to run ~22 queries on each.

I have attempted to use MySQLdb, asyncio, and ThreadPoolExecutor but keep receiving a segmentation fault.  To be quite honest neither am I sure this is the best approach nor am I sure I'm coding this correctly.

````
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
import sys
import os
import configparser
import datetime
import logging
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
import MySQLdb

def setup():

    #Some Setup stuff here

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(Main(dbServers, mySQLuser, mySQLpass, db_ignore_list, trunc_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), logger))
    finally:
        event_loop.close()

async def Main(dbServers, mySQLuser, mySQLpass, db_ignore_list, trunc_date, logger):
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host=dbServers, user=mySQLuser, passwd=mySQLpass)
    except:
        logger.critical('Error connecting to the Database server {}'.format(dbServers))
        quit()

    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute('SHOW DATABASES')
    databases = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]
    db_list = list(set(databases) - set(db_ignore_list))

    # Generator Object for .map
    args = ((db,s,trunc_date) for s in db_list)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        executor.map(lambda p: archive_table(*p), args)
    db.close()

def archive_table(db, schema, trunc_date):
    cur = db.cursor()
    db.select_db(schema)
    cur.execute('SOME SQL') #x22
    cur.execute('SOME SQL') #x22
    cur.execute('SOME SQL') #x22
    cur.execute('SOME SQL') #x22
    db.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
````

Comment: 700 databases?!? What on Earth gave rise to this situation?

Comment: Yes this was my exclamation as well, but unfortunately its what I have to work with =(

Comment: I think you probably mean tables in a database, rather than distinct databases. Surely?

Comment: I do not.  There are in fact ~that many DBs per server